# How to change a value from AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-alertdialog

As long as an `EditText` with `ListView` is difficult to figure out, I tried another solution : A `ListView` with `TextViews` and when you click on one, I catch the focused `TextView` with a listener (a `OnItemClickListener` on the parent `ListView`) and I open an `AlertDialog`.

**ISSUE** : When I press the OK button on the `AlertDialog`, I want the focused `TextView` to get the text value of the alert dialog's `EditText`, but it doesn't work, he keeps the same text value. On activity :

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id){

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);

            id ++;
            t = new TextView(activity);
            t = (TextView) v;

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

            alert.setTitle("Title");
            alert.setMessage("Message");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
            final EditText input = new EditText(activity);
            input.setText(t.getText());
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    //Changer la valeur dans la base et dans la liste


                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS,0);

                    t.setText(input.getText());

                    System.out.println("input avant : " + t.getText());
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });


            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

I think this code is enough for you to know what's wrong in my code. Just to let you know :

- `ListView` and *t* (`TextView`) are declared as private variables on the activity class
- there is an `Adapter` class that builds automatically the `TextView` list
- if I change the value of an `EditText` on the `ListView` listener, it works, but in the dialog alert listener, it doesn't.

Ask if you want more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you built your adapter so I will guess an answer. You'll have to put your text in the adapter data(for example in the `ArrayList` that you give to your adapter) and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

```
//ArrayList field on which your adapter is based ?!?(if you used this)
private ArrayList<String> items;

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, final View v, int pos, long id){

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

            alert.setTitle("Title");
            alert.setMessage("Message");
            final EditText input = new EditText(activity);
            input.setText(t.getText());
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    items.set(pos, input.getText().toString());
                    adapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();  // the adapter you set in the listView.setAdapter();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });


            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh my god your right. It's like I did a custom adapter but don't know how to use it. Anyway I begin on android. Thanks !

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND If all you want is a row with a `TextView` in it you'll be better off with a simple `ArrayAdapter<String>`. Custom adapters are for when you want to customize the row layout or have a more complex data structure.

Comment: Yeah you're right, thanks for advice, but I need it to be more complex  in the future